# A list of points inside a list of class objects

Tags: c#, list, class, point

Here is a snippet of a class definition:

```
 public class Dinosaur
{
    public string Specie { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<System.Windows.Point> Location { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public Dinosaur()
    {

    }
}
```

Now we create a list:

```
        public static List<Dinosaur> Dinosaurs = new List<Dinosaur>();
```

Now we want to create and add a list of points.

```
 List<System.Windows.Point> Location = new List<System.Windows.Point>();

            for (int y = (int)pt.Y - 5; y <= (int)pt.Y + 5; y++)
                for (int x = (int)pt.X - 5; x <= (int)pt.X + 5; x++)
                    Location.Add (new System.Windows.Point (x, y ));

            Dinosaurs.Last().Location.AddRange(Location);
```

The last line is throwing a null pointer exception. This is weird because Location has 121 good values.

Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a *question* as such...

Comment: Check out the Add method on List

Comment: Do you want one location per dinosaur or a list of locations for each dinosaur?

Comment: Btw, your dinosaurs location is static, so that means they share the location. Maybe because there is just one dino left. However, you should change that.

Comment: I'm curious why `Location` is static? Given that you are likely to have more than one `Dinosoar`, I'd imagine you want each one to have its own independent list of `Point`? Also, minor thing, but I'd name that `Locations`, given that it can contain _n Points_, not just a single `Point`

Comment: @Michael: I assume its a list because it is a drawn dinosaur.

Comment: @TimSchmelter hmm yeah just seemed odd - there's not much context in the qu, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: Location shouldn't be static! Thanks for catching that, too. It changes 'every turn'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list `Location` shouldn't be static because of you're calling Last() method.

```
public class Dinosaur
        {
            public string Specie { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public List<System.Windows.Point> Location { get; set; } // this shouldn't be static

            // Constructor
            public Dinosaur()
            {

            }
        }

    public static List<Dinosaur> Dinosaurs = new List<Dinosaur>(); // your list of dinosaurs somewhere

    List<System.Windows.Point> yourListOfPoints = new List<System.Windows.Point>(); // create a new list of points to add
    yourListOfPoints.Add(new Point { X = pixelMousePositionX, Y = oldLocation.Y }); // add some points to list
    Dinosaurs.Last().Location.AddRange(yourListOfPoints); // select last dinosaur from list and assign your list of points to it's location property
```

**Edit**

You have to create a list in your constructor, before you actually use it:

```
public List<System.Windows.Point> Location { get; set; }

// Constructor
public Dinosaur()
{
    Location = new List<System.Windows.Points>();
}
```

or replace:

```
Dinosaurs.Last().Location.AddRange(Location);
```

with:

```
Dinosaurs.Last().Location = Location;
```

Comment: Yes, Location being static was an error. Thanks for catching it!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Hey, this worked, but it's throwing a null pointer... Weird... I'll edit the above for more info

Comment: Thanks! That was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
var points =
    from d in Dinosaurs
    select d.Location;
```

Based on your question, I'm not sure if this is what you were asking for.

Edit:
Ok, I would likely set the List in the constructor of the Dinosaur class.  Then where I want to add a series of points to it I would have this code.

```
IEnumerable<Point> points = getPointsFromSomewhere();
myDinosaurObject.Location.AddRange(points);
```

Comment: How does that create and add a list of points?

Comment: How would I add a list of points to Dinosaurs.Location?

Comment: As I mentioned, investigate the Add method on List. It looks like MyList.Add(new Point(x, y)) for each point. You can also add a range of Point.

Comment: But I wouldn't likely expose the whole List<Point> publicly, I would expose a property with the type IEnumerable<Point> then add an AddRange method to Dinosaur that would call the AddRange method of a private List<Point>.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the question is about your initialisation of, or addition to `List<Point> Locations`, in addition to the above (although I don't believe it's preferable in this case), you could use a [collection initialiser:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx)

```
List<Point> Locations = new List<Point>()
        {
            new Point(1, 2),
            new Point(3, 4),
            new Point(5, 6),
            new Point(1, 1)
        };
```

I would go with the `AddRange` option though.